# standard kinect dataset

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
are there any standard dataset of kinect (like) sensor for evaluating results?

prince.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37052/standard-kinect-dataset/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Evaluating results of what? Tabletop object detection? 3D SLAM?

For 3D slam with color information, there are some datasets [here](http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset) (the bagfiles contain depth and rgb images from the Kinect, and there is a script to compute point clouds from them if you need that).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fsales](https://answers.ros.org/users/7801/fsales/) on 2014-03-18**:
Hi, Can you point my to that mentioned script?

thank you.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-03-18**:
Sure, here you go: http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/tools#adding_point_clouds_to_ros_bag_files

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-03-18**:
BTW, you should use that script only to work with the RGBDSLAM-Bagfiles. If you just want to record depth images yourself and add point clouds later, this method is better: http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback